# How can I arrange elements in a javax.swing.* GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a GUI  with 3 components arranged vertically centered in the middle. Now I've created the components but I cannot find a way to add them vertically on top of each other vertically. I've tried making different panels and different layouts and I get something different every time. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class EquationSolverGUI extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;;

    public EquationSolverGUI() {
        super("Equation Solver");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
        inputPanel.add(input);

        JTextField output = new JTextField(20);
        outputPanel.add(output);

        JButton solve = new JButton("Solve");
        buttonPanel.add(solve);

        add(input);
        add(output);
        add(solve);
        
        panel.add(inputPanel);
        panel.add(outputPanel);
        panel.add(buttonPanel);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        EquationSolverGUI equationSolver = new EquationSolverGUI();
        equationSolver.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding your components to one panel. Put a GridBagLayout on this panel and fiddle around with GridBagConstraints only.

Comment: @user16320675 -- I thought that "**Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.**" was proof that it needed a change, however, I have since flagged the post so a moderator can decide the best form.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), in particular [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
.  `GridBagLayout` is the most flexible and most complicated in built layout manager, so I'll forgive you if it wasn't immediately obvious.

Based on your needs, I don't think you need individual panels for the components and they could easily be laid out on the same container.  If you wanted to have more then one button, grouped together, then I would consider using another panel for those, but the basic concept would otherwise remains the same.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField output = new JTextField(20);
            JButton solve = new JButton("Solve");

            add(input, gbc);
            add(output, gbc);
            add(solve, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

Change this line...

`setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));`

...to be this instead...

`setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));`

...and that will fix everything.

The reason why this fixes everything is because the constructor accepts 2 parameters -- [rows and columns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int)). If you set rows to 10, you will get 10 rows. If you set columns to 20, you will get 20, and so on.

However, if you set ***either rows or columns (NOT BOTH)*** to equal 0, then you will be permitted to add an infinite number of elements without any unexpected formatting errors.

For example, if I want 20 (or so) elements stacked on top of each other, I would do `new GridLayout(0, 1)`, which is another of saying ***I want some number of rows, but only 1 column***, which is another way of saying, just make one column of an indefinite amount of elements. It works vice versa for horizontal, just make it `new GridLayout(1, 0)`.

This is important because if you try to plug in more elements than expected, and you don't use the 0-style format, you will get unexpected and likely unwanted results. Here is an example.

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class LayoutTrouble
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      gridLayoutWithMoreElementsThanPlanned(3, 1, 300, 400);
      gridLayoutWithMoreElementsThanPlanned(0, 1, 600, 400);
   
   }

   private static void gridLayoutWithMoreElementsThanPlanned(final int rows, final int columns, final int x, final int y)
   {
   
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   
      panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
      
      panel.add(new JButton("1"));
      panel.add(new JButton("2"));
      panel.add(new JButton("3"));
      panel.add(new JButton("4"));
   
      frame.add(panel);
      
      frame.setTitle("4 buttons in a " + rows + " by " + columns);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(300, 300);
      frame.setLocation(x, y);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }
   
}
```

[image: A picture of the problem]

As you can see in this image, using the 0-style protects you from accidentally miscounting the number of elements. Now, the result remains as expected without any surprises.

As you can see though, you can still add an infinite number of elements without using 0-style, but I strongly recommend that you do not do this. The behaviour is difficult to follow, and unnecessarily complicates your domain. Instead, it's much easier to either use 0-style, or find some way to assert the number of elements being added.

Comment: Note: even if setting **BOTH rows and columns**, you will be permitted to add an infinite number of elements - as documented: "When both the number of rows and the number of columns have been set to non-zero values, ..., the number of columns specified is ignored."

Comment: @user16320675 That is correct, thank you for adding. That said, I would encourage all to use the '0-style' when adding variable number of elements. Ignoring the fact that it clearly communicates intent, it also guarantees a very specific style of formatting. You don't always get that if you set both rows and columns to a non-zero value.

Comment: "*You don't always get that if you set both rows and columns to a non-zero value.*" ? How not? If both are set to non-zero, you get exactly the same as setting column number to zero; as documented! (also note: OP is not "*adding variable number of elements*" {but the wrong ones - 4 instead of 3})

Comment: I think we are approaching the same solution from different directions. I have edited my example to better demonstrate it, but long story short - if you want all your elements to be placed into a single column, you might do `new GridLayout(3, 1)`. I am saying, avoid putting the 3, since what you really want is a single column of elements. Instead, replace the 3 with 0, and add elements freely. If you put 3 anyways, and you make a mistake of adding more than you planned, then your formatting will not do what you originally wanted. Rather, it will make a second column, which isn't what you want

Comment: I understand now. You are taking issue with the fact that my answer does not communicate that adding infinite number of elements is possible even if they don't use 0-style. If that is what you mean, then that is exactly what I wanted to communicate. I DO NOT want readers to consider the possibility of adding infinite elements to a non 0-style GridLayout. I feel that that is bad practice, and something I do not want to encourage. I will include it anyways in the name of knowledge exchange, but I will also firmly dissuade others from using it, as I believe it is prone to cause errors.

Comment: NO, it is NOT that it "does not communicate that adding infinite number of elements is possible even if they don't use 0-style", not directly! The problem is that it suggests or communicates that it is not permitted if not using the "0-style". It may be bad practice, but it is **permitted**!  (( the possible error is not being aware of how it works, that is, not having read the documentation - providing both numbers works exactly the same as having column number set to zero, that is, exactly the same as a "0-style GridLayout" ))

Comment: I understand now. I still feel that because it is bad practice, I do not want to even make it known that it is a possibility. I feel that that is the most responsible way. But in spite of that, I have already edited my answer to include that information. To better explain 0-style, technically yes, 3, 1 will give you the same results 3, 0. However, I consider that a poor design choice, and even allowing that distinction to be made pointlessly muddles the water in my mind.

Comment: As for why I told them not to use 3, 0 - they wanted a single column, so rows must be 0. Either rows or columns having 0 is 0-style. I don't make a distinction between the two. But in their case, they placed the 0 in the wrong parameter, so I moved it to mean what they actually intended.

Comment: So be it, I won't push it any further.